# Update parent entity before inserting child entity

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, persistence

I have two entities, BidirectionalActivity(Parent) and Conversation (Child).
I want to save parent first and once my Conversation or child is created I want to update parent table and insert in child.

```
Below is my Schema

CREATE TABLE BIDIRECTIONAL_ACTIVITIES (
id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
status VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
conversationId bigint(20),
PRIMARY KEY(id)
} 

create unique index index_conversationId on BIDIRECTIONAL_ACTIVITIES(conversationId);

CREATE TABLE CONVERSATION (
id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(id),
FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES BIDIRECTIONAL_ACTIVITIES(conversationId)
);
```

Here is mapping in hibernate OneToOne:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BIDIRECTIONAL_ACTIVITIES")
public class BidirectionalActivity implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="status")
    private String status;

   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="bidirectionalActivity", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="conversationId")
    private Conversation conversation;
}


@Entity
@Table(name="CONVERSATION")
public class Conversation implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private BidirectionalActivity bidirectionalActivity;
}
```

DAO Layer

```
public class BidirectionalActivityDAOImpl  implements BidirectionalActivityDAO {
 @Autowired
 private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
 @Override
 public void addBidirectionalActivity(BidirectionalActivity bidirectionalActivity) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.saveOrUpdate(bidirectionalActivity);
    }
}
```

Service Layer:

```
@Component
public class BidirectionalActivityServiceImpl implements BidirectionalActivityService {
    @Autowired
    BidirectionalActivityDAO BidirectionalActivityDAO;
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public Integer addBidirectionalActivity(BidirectionalActivity bidirectionalActivity) {
        return BidirectionalActivityDAO.addBidirectionalActivity(bidirectionalActivity);
    }
```

My Test Case:

```
BidirectionalActivity bidirectionalActivity = new BidirectionalActivity();
bidirectionalActivity.setStatus("Active");
Integer persistedIdBiderectionalActivity = bidirectionalActivityService.addBidirectionalActivity(bidirectionalActivity);

Conversation conversation = new Conversation();
conversation.setBidirectionalActivity(persistedBidActvty);
        persistedBidActvty.setConversation(conversation);
   bidirectionalActivityService.addBidirectionalActivity(persistedBidActvty);
```

I was expecting hibernate first executes insert statement on parent table and second time it should update parent table first and then child table. 
however , its just doing insert for second time on child table.

```
insert into CONVERSATION values ( )
```

and i am getting error:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`CONVERSATION`, CONSTRAINT `CONVERSATION_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `BIDIRECTIONAL_ACTIVITIES` (`conversationId`))
```

Comment: Something is wrong with your reasoning. How is your "parent table" bidirectional at all when it only has the reference to one conversation? Also, why don't you insert the conversation _first_ (and grab its id) then insert the parent?

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is when a new row goes into `CONVERSATION` it is being assigned an auto_incrementing `id` by the system.

Your foreign key constraint enforces referential integrity (RI) by making sure that same `id` exists in a row in the *referenced* table `BIDIRECTIONAL_ACTIVITIES` in column `conversationId`. Such a row does not exist.

Perhaps it is not your desire to have set up your **RI** as such.

Perhaps this is what you really meant to do:

```
CREATE TABLE CONVERSATION
(
   id bigint(20) PRIMARY KEY,
   FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES BIDIRECTIONAL_ACTIVITIES(conversationId)
);
```

Simply ditching the `AUTO_INCREMENT` aspect from it and manually putting in the PK id that is determined from the parent insert in that certain column `conversationId` in a prior step.

Regardless, you need to rethink this whole thing.

Comment: So what is the best way to do this?

Comment: For RI (and it is darn good you want this) make sure such a row exists in the *referenced* table `BIDIRECTIONAL_ACTIVITIES` prior to the insert to the *referencing* table `CONVERSATION`. How one performs this via Hibernate is above my skill level. But, as it all rests on top of the RI system of mysql, that is what that error is telling you.

Comment: You really need to step back and consider why you are setting it up like this. You simply do not know what the `id` is going to be in the child table. There could be innodb engine gaps or various other reasons. So, again, the setup and the expectation seems quite wrong.